# load VHDL sram from a file

Tags: vhdl

I was curious why the following code doesn't work to load an sram memory array in VHDL?  What am I missing?

here's my input file: ram_image.hex

```
be
ef
ca
fe
34
23
```

Here's the code where i attempt to load my_ram using the impure function load_sram_hex.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
use std.textio.all; 

entity sram is
end entity;
```

```vhdl
architecture beh of sram is
    constant sram_dw    :integer := 8;
    constant sram_aw    :integer := 4;
    constant sram_depth :integer := 2**sram_aw - 1;
    
    type sram_t is array (0 to sram_depth-1) of std_logic_vector(sram_dw downto 0);
```

```vhdl
    impure function load_sram_hex(filename : in string) return sram_t is
        file     f    :text is in filename;
        variable b    :line;
        variable mem  :sram_t;
        variable good :boolean;
        variable m    :line;    
    begin
        for i in sram_t'range loop
            readline(f, b);
            hread(b, mem(i), good);
            
            write(m, string'("HERE=> ") );
            hwrite(m, mem(i));          
            writeline(output, m);
            
            if (not good) then              
                exit;
            end if;
            
        end loop;
        return mem;
    end function;
```

```vhdl
    signal my_ram : sram_t := load_sram_hex("ram_image.hex");
begin
  
process
    variable m :line;
begin
    wait for 10 ns;
    
    for i in sram_t'range loop
        write(m, string'("ram["));
        write(m, i);
        write(m, string'("] = "));
        hwrite(m, my_ram(i));
        writeline(output, m);
    end loop;
    
    wait for 1000 ns;
    report "just kidding! end of testbench" severity failure; 
end process;

end architecture;
```

Here you can see the output of the vhdl simulation is just x's even tough i loaded the memory...

```
## run all
ram[0] = XXX
ram[1] = XXX
ram[2] = XXX
ram[3] = XXX
ram[4] = XXX
ram[5] = XXX
ram[6] = XXX
ram[7] = XXX
ram[8] = XXX
ram[9] = XXX
ram[10] = XXX
ram[11] = XXX
ram[12] = XXX
ram[13] = XXX
ram[14] = XXX
Failure: just kidding! end of testbench
Time: 1010 ns  Iteration: 0  Process: /sram/line__52  File: sram.vhd
```

Comment: https://vhdlwhiz.com/initialize-ram-from-file/

Comment: Use assert/report to see what's going on in the init function. Does each word of data make it into the RAM? How big is the RAM and does the file fill all of it? If the file ends early, what does the function return?

Comment: I already know its not getting called because it suppose to print " write(m, string'("HERE=> ") );"

Comment: maybe a bug in the Vivado Simulator?

Comment: `%: ghdl -r sram
../../src/synopsys/std_logic_textio.vhdl:380:25:@0ms:(assertion error): HWRITE Error: Trying to read vector with an odd (non multiple of 4) length
HERE=>
../../src/synopsys/std_logic_textio.vhdl:380:25:@10ns:(assertion error): HWRITE Error: Trying to read vector with an odd (non multiple of 4) length ram[0] = ...` That's the `hwrite(m, mem(i));`. Where `type sram_t is array (0 to sram_depth-1) of std_logic_vector(sram_dw downto 0);` has a range 8 downto 0. should be sram_dw - 1.

Comment: It looks like there are some missing diagnostic output from the Vivado Simulator for Synopsys package std_logic_textio, or you missed the the output. The former seems likely. You also get an assertion error for not having enough datums in your ram_image.hex file.

Comment: -2008 also has an IEEE package std_logic_textio but *should* require you to not use -1987 file declaration syntax to imply file opening and would not report the same diagnostics. (HREAD is found in package std_logic_1164).

Answer (score 0):

This worked in vivado simulator for me:

```vhdl
-- FILE: ram_image.hex
-- ab
-- 12
-- ef
-- 14
-- 34
-- 23

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all; 

entity sram is
end entity;

architecture beh of sram is
    constant sram_dw    :integer := 8;
    constant sram_aw    :integer := 4;
    constant sram_depth :integer := 2**sram_aw - 1;
    
    type sram_t is array (0 to sram_depth-1) of std_logic_vector(sram_dw-1 downto 0);
    
    shared variable my_ram   :sram_t;    

    procedure hread_backport( 
        l     :inout  line; 
        value :out    std_logic_vector
    ) is
        variable offset  :integer;
        variable c       :character;
        variable good1   :boolean;
        variable hex_val :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    begin
        offset := 0;
        value  := (others => '0');      
        while (offset < value'high) loop            
            read(l, c, good1);
            if (not good1) then exit; end if;              
            case c is
            when '0'       => hex_val := "0000";
            when '1'       => hex_val := "0001";
            when '2'       => hex_val := "0010";
            when '3'       => hex_val := "0011";
            when '4'       => hex_val := "0100";
            when '5'       => hex_val := "0101";
            when '6'       => hex_val := "0110";
            when '7'       => hex_val := "0111";
            when '8'       => hex_val := "1000";
            when '9'       => hex_val := "1001";
            when 'A' | 'a' => hex_val := "1010";
            when 'B' | 'b' => hex_val := "1011";
            when 'C' | 'c' => hex_val := "1100";
            when 'D' | 'd' => hex_val := "1101";
            when 'E' | 'e' => hex_val := "1110";
            when 'F' | 'f' => hex_val := "1111";               
            when others =>
                hex_val := "XXXX";
                assert false report "Found non-hex character'" & c & "'";
            end case;
            value( (value'high-offset) downto (value'high-offset-3) ) := hex_val;
            offset := offset + 4;
        end loop;
    end procedure;
    
    procedure sram_load_hex(filepath :string) is
        file  f           :text;
        variable b, m     :line;
        variable good     :boolean;
    begin   
        write(m, string'("opening file: ") & filepath );
        writeline(output, m);   
        file_open(f, filepath, read_mode);
        
        for i in sram_t'range loop
            if (endfile(f)) then exit; end if;
            readline(f, b);
            hread_backport(b, my_ram(i));           
        end loop;           
    end procedure;
    
    procedure sram_print_hex is
        variable m     :line;
    begin
        for i in sram_t'range loop
            write(m, string'("read ram["));
            write(m, i);
            write(m, string'("] = "));
            hwrite(m, my_ram(i));
            writeline(output, m);
        end loop;       
    end procedure;
    
begin
  
process 
begin
    sram_load_hex("C:/Users/racerx/Desktop/sandbox/sram/ram_image.hex");
    wait;
end process;
  
process
begin
    wait for 1000 ns;
    sram_print_hex;
    report "just kidding! end of testbench" severity failure; 
end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).